# Email a SharePoint group with MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, outlook, flow, send-email

I want to send an email via Outlook when a new file is added to a library, but I want to send that mail to a SharePoint group.

How can I do it? Is it possible?

If its not possible, what will be the best to achieve this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no action available to send an email to a SharePoint group. But, you can achieve the same using below workaround:

1. Create a flow which will trigger on a file creation in document library.
2. Get SharePoint group users using **Send an HTTP Request to SharePoint** Action in flow.
3. Loop through the response you got from above step and send an email using **Send an email** action in flow.

Below references will help you to achieve the same:

1. [Flow: Send Email to SharePoint Group Members](https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2018/12/flow-send-email-to-sharepoint-group-members/).
2. [Email a SharePoint group from a Flow](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/email-a-sharepoint-group-from-a-flow/).

Comment: for reference, it seems like `HTTP` connector is a premium connector, which is a show stopper for many, see:  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/HTTP-Premium-Connector/td-p/276213

Comment: I have not mentioned premium HTTP connector here. I am talking about the [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#send-an-http-request-to-SharePoint) action which comes with **free SharePoint Connector**.

Comment: oh, thank you for the information, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Once you do it once, it should be smooth sailings.  A shame you can't IDE the name of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can go step by step for sending email to SharePoint group using Flow:

1. Create Flow (select Automated cloud flow), flow name (EmailtoSPGroup), Trigger (When Item is created/modified) and click on "Create" Button
2. Provide the site name and select the list from the drop down
3. Click on "+ New Step" and select "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint"
4. Provide below details:
   Site Name: Your site URL
   Method: GET
   URI: _api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('SiteName Members')/users?$select=Email
5. Click on Save and click on Test the flow from top right side
6. in execution results phase, click on "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action expand output section and copy the content from body section
7. Edit the flow Again, add "Parse Json" action
8. Select Content = Body (from dynamic content)
9. Schema section= Click on Generate from Sample and paste the code (which you have copied in earlier step) and click on Okay, it will convert to JSON objects automatically
10. Add a next action , "Initialize variable"  with the below fields
    Name = "EmailVar"
    Type = String
11. Add action, "Apply to Each" and update the below fields
    Select an output from previous steps = Results (from Dynamic content)
    within this action, click on "Add an action"
    Append to String variable action with below fields
    Name = Email from dropdown
    Value - Email(from dynamic content)
12. New Step, Send an email (V2) with below fields
    To = Email (from variable section in dynamic content)
    Subject= your wish, body= your content
13. Click on Save
14. Test Run
15. update list item and then your flow will trigger email to members of the provided group

Thanks,
Srini